# How to free node after deletion in linklist in C

Tags: c, free

I have a very basic doubt. I created a linklist using structure and this is my delete code.

```
void delete(int num)
{
struct node* temp=head;
struct node* prev=head;
if(temp == NULL)
printf("List Empty\n");
else
{
while(temp != NULL)
{
    if(temp->value == num)
    {
            prev=temp->next;
            free(temp);     
            break;
    }
    else
    {       
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp->next;        

    }
}
```

After running this code, the node is not getting deleted. If I print temp->value after free(temp), the value is 0. But this should not be the case. The free should wipe the node. So I don't understand from where the 0 appears. Any idea what is wrong with this code ?

My show function:

```
void show()
{
struct node *temp = head;
while(temp != NULL)
{
printf("----  %d  ---- ", temp->value);
temp=temp->next;
}
printf("\n\n");
}
```

My struct:

```
struct node
{
int value;
int pos;
struct node* next;
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find the node in `delete`:

```
if(temp->value == num)
{
        prev=temp->next;
        free(temp);     
        break;
}
```

You don't actually make the previous nodes next-pointer point to the nodes next link.

Instead you should do e.g.

```
prev->next = temp->next;
```

Comment: Cool. This handles all the cases expect the head case. I am still getting 0 if I delete the first element. So, according to my code, if I delete temp, then head would also get deleted ? Do I need to put special condition to handle deletion of the first node ?

Comment: if (temp==head) {head=temp->next;} This condition will handle the case. Thanks